# bs4: skipping AttributeError in for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I'm web scraping for the first time and ran into a problem.
I have to get the product price certain products (the url in the code), however, when a there is a discount on a product, it will give an error. This is the code that I have right now (deleted a couple lines that were in-between, but it works like this):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import csv
#import pandas as pd

links = []


url='https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken?page={page}'
for page in range(1,2):
    req = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.select('div[class="product-card-portrait_content__2xN-b"] a'):
        abs_url = 'https://www.ah.nl' + link.get('href')
        #print(abs_url)
   
        #GETTING THE PRICE
        p_price = []
        req4 = requests.get(abs_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req4.content, 'html.parser')
        p_price = (soup.find(class_='price-amount_root__37xv2 product-card-hero-price_now__PlF9u')).text
```

And the output is this:

```
runcell(0, '/Users/eva/Desktop/MDDD/TestingProduct.py')
0.55
0.35
2.99
0.65
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/Users/eva/Desktop/MDDD/TestingProduct.py", line 22, in <module>
    p_price = (soup.find(class_='price-amount_root__37xv2 product-card-hero-price_now__PlF9u')).text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So it gives me the first four prices and then the error. I tried to work around it adding this:

```
 if p_price != AttributeError:continue
```

But that didn't work. I don't mind if the products that have discount aren't in the dataset. Any tips on how to keep the for loop going - so deleting the prices that give the error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting NoneType error because all items didn't containt price and to get rid  of this error, you can use `if else None statement`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import csv
#import pandas as pd

links = []


url='https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken?page={page}'
for page in range(1,2):
    req = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.select('div[class="product-card-portrait_content__2xN-b"] a'):
        abs_url = 'https://www.ah.nl' + link.get('href')
        #print(abs_url)
   
        #GETTING THE PRICE
        p_price = []
        req4 = requests.get(abs_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req4.content, 'html.parser')
        p_price = (soup.find(class_='price-amount_root__37xv2 product-card-hero-price_now__PlF9u'))
        p_price = p_price.text if p_price else None
        print(p_price)
```

**Output:**

```
0.55
0.35
2.99
0.65
None
0.49
0.65
0.59
0.92
0.99
0.79
0.55
0.65
2.19
3.00
2.00
0.89
0.89
0.66
0.89
0.89
1.25
1.99
1.19
0.99
0.79
1.79
1.99
1.79
6.29
1.19
1.39
2.19
0.65
1.95
0.79
None
None
None
None
2.00
2.29
0.49
1.29
1.55
1.59
1.39
2.99
2.00
0.99
1.39
1.65
1.19
0.99
0.99
2.29
1.99
2.69
0.49
0.99
0.79
2.19
2.00
3.69
0.89
2.29
0.45
1.85
2.00
2.00
5.99
1.09
2.79
1.19
3.29
0.95
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the price from the results pages without visiting each individual link. Additionally, by judicious use of css :not() pseudo-class selector you can exclude the old prices, where discounts appear, this then removes the error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken?page={page}'

for page in range(1, 3):
    print(f"Page: {page}")
    print()
    req = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    for product in soup.select('[data-testhook="product-card"]'):
        print(product.select_one('[data-testhook="product-title"]').get_text(strip=True))
        print(product.select_one('[data-testhook="price-amount"]:not([class*=price_was])').text)
    print()
```

---

If wanting to check for gluten, there is a gluten free icon on some of the product pages. Be wary of false positives e.g. *AH Tomatenblokjes gesneden* single can is marked as gluten free but there is no such labelling for the *AH Tomatenblokjes gesneden 4-pack*. Same product, different labelling.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken?page={page}'

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1, 3):
        print(f"Page: {page}")
        print()
        req = s.get(url.format(page=page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

        for product in soup.select('[data-testhook="product-card"]'):
            print(product.select_one('[data-testhook="product-title"]').get_text(strip=True))
            print(product.select_one('[data-testhook="price-amount"]:not([class*=price_was])').text)
            print(f"Gluten free: {'svg--glutenvrij' in s.get('https://www.ah.nl' + product.select_one('a[class^=link_root]')['href']).text}")
            print()
```

Comment: I was visiting each individual link because I als need to get the allergy information! But I don't think that's possible without visiting each individual link?

Comment: what allergy info in particular?

Comment: for every product I need to know if it contains gluten

Comment: Eva, I decided to look into the gluten labelling. Want to work with me to see if we can reduce the false positives I mention above?

Comment: sorry only just now saw your reply! (stress due to thesis deadline - studying design but having to code as well :') I luckily got it to work. I just posted a new question. Any chance you can take a look at that?